# Failed to deploy source to org

Tags: deployment, error, api-version

Given:

```
      I am trying to deploy helloWorld project but its unable to deploy project and giving errors listed below.Instead of getting ended with exit code 0 I am getting Deploy Errors
      Create a Hello World Lightning Web Component(in vs code)
```

When:

```
1)"sourceApiVersion": "52.0" for .json file
2)<apiVersion>45.0</apiVersion>for.xml file.
3)file>preference>settings: java home:"salesforcedx-vscode-apex.java.home": "C:\\Program 
  Files\\AdoptOpenJDK\\jdk-11.0.9.101-hotspot",
4)SFDX VERSION:sfdx-cli/7.129.0 win32-x64 node-v16.13.0
```

THEN:

```
1)SFDX: Deploy Source to Org failed to run
2)SOURCE:Salesforce CLI integeration(Extension)
3)PROJECT PATH  ERRORS
4)Cannot find Lightning Component Bundle new projectsfdc.
```

for reference similar problems:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58473686/lwc-deployment-error-while-deploying-from-vs-code/60310677#60310677
```

other information:

```
1)my api version are different.What should I do?
2)Also:PROJECT PATH  ERRORS(getting this)
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Please take some time to [edit] your post (and use the formatting tools in the editor) to clearly state your issue. Try using the "given/when/then" format: given your setup, when you do X, you get Y (instead of the expected Z). See [ask] for more.

Comment: I have set the API VERSIONS to 52.0 but still getting the error